# SQL select youngest record

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table. I want to run the SQL query and select the youngest record per `ID`, I also need to output all other columns associated with the youngest row. In the real table, there are more than 500+ columns.

Please note, I am using AWS Athena. The table has no indexes.

```
ID  COL1    COL2    LAST_UPDATED
1   yyy     ddd     01/01/2020
1   ccc     eee     12/01/2020
2   xxx     ddd     02/01/2020
2   vvv     eee     19/01/2020
```

Desired result:

```
ID  COL1    COL2    LAST_UPDATED
1   ccc     eee     12/01/2020
2   vvv     eee     19/01/2020
```

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT id, updated_at, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at desc) rn
     from table t
)
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical and efficient way in most databases is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.LAST_UPDATED = (select max(t2.LAST_UPDATED)
                        from t t2
                        where t2.id = t.id
                       );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(id, LAST_UPDATED)`.

In a database that doesn't have indexes, then use `row_nmber()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by last_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I am using AWS Athena - the table has no indexes. What do you think the performance would be in this case?

Comment: How that would work if two records in t have the same timestamp, don't you need to group by id?

Comment: @WildGoat . . . You would have to try it.  I don't know how well Presto optimizes subqueries (some parallel databases do a good job).  Hopefully you have learned to tag your questions correctly so you get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query:

```
 select * from aws 
 where last_updated in (select max(last_updated) from aws group by id)
```